# Exception encountered when calling layer "model_5" (type Functional)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

This is the following code :

## Hyper parameters

```
batch_size = 64
nb_epoch = 50
```

## Parameters for dataset

```
img_rows, img_cols = 160, 160
nb_classes = 10
```

## Parameters for network

```
nb_lstm_outputs = 30
nb_time_steps = img_rows
dim_input_vector = img_cols
```

```
print('X_train original shape:', trainX.shape)
input_shape = (nb_time_steps, dim_input_vector)

trainX = trainX.astype('float32') / 255.
testX = testX.astype('float32') / 255.
trainY = np_utils.to_categorical(trainY, nb_classes)
testY = np_utils.to_categorical(testY, nb_classes)

print('X_train shape:', trainX.shape)
print(trainX.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(testX.shape[0], 'test samples')
```

## Utility for our sequence model.

def get_sequence_model():

```
class_vocab = label_processor.get_vocabulary()
frame_features_input = keras.Input((input_shape))

x = keras.layers.GRU(16, return_sequences=True)(frame_features_input)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(x)
x = keras.layers.GRU(8)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="relu")(x)

output = keras.layers.Dense(len(class_vocab), activation="softmax")(x)
rnn_model = keras.Model(frame_features_input, output)

rnn_model.compile(
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"]
)
return rnn_model
```

## Utility for running experiments.

def run_experiment():

```
seq_model = get_sequence_model()
history = seq_model.fit(
    x = trainX,
    y = trainY,
    batch_size=64, 
    epochs=500, 
    validation_data=(testX, testY)
)

# seq_model.load_weights(filepath)
_, accuracy = seq_model.evaluate([test_data[0], test_data[1]], test_labels)
print(f"Test accuracy: {round(accuracy * 100, 2)}%")

return history, seq_model
```

```
_, sequence_model = run_experiment()
```

I am getting the following error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enlOH.png)
Why am I getting the following error and how can I solve it?

```
Epoch 1/500
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 160, 160) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 160, 160), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_32'), name='input_32', description="created by layer 'input_32'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 160, 160, 3).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-a1d4870dee01> in <module>
     40 
     41 
---> 42 _, sequence_model = run_experiment()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 214, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model_9" (type Functional).
    
    Input 0 of layer "gru_29" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 160, 160, 3)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "model_9" (type Functional):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 160, 160, 3), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

Can't solve this problem can someone help?

Comment: GRU layers do not receive images as inputs, the input shape should be (samples, timesteps, features). Are you sure this is really sequence data?